# Align Dynamic Dialog on top

Tags: angular, primeng

Is it possible to align the [Dynamic Dialog](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dynamicdialog) component on top when opening?

I am using a proposed way of showing it:

```
show() {
    const ref = this.dialogService.open(CarsListDemo, {
        header: 'Choose a Car',
        width: '70%'
    });
}
```

Comment: i hope you are using z-index: 1002; if this didn' t help please post your code.

Comment: The only code I am using is as provided in the question. There is a button which calls the 'show' function, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the 'style'(Inline style of the component) object on the open dialog.

```
 onClick() {
    this.dialogService.open(DialogComponent,
     {
      style: {
         backgroundColor: '#fff',
        // 'min-width': '100px',
        // 'min-height': '100px',
        position: 'absolute',
        overflow: 'auto',
        top: '300px',
        right: '100px',
        bottom: 0,
        left: 500,
        'overflow-y': 'auto',
      },
      header: 'Choose a Car',

    });
  }
```

Demo is here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-fxeygh-zala3a